# Using sed command to print the first column of /etc/group file

Tags: linux, sed, group

I'm trying to use `sed` command in order to print the first column of the `/etc/group` file.
If someone have an idea, please share.

Comment: Easier to use `cut -f1 -d: /etc/group` ?  Unless this is a homework question and you MUST use `sed`....

Comment: Also, it's best to use `getent group | cut -f1 -d:` instead of using /etc/group directly.   Groups can be defined in a lot more places than just /etc/group - ldap, nis/yp, db files, sql databases, and more.  `getent` searches whichever are in use on the system.   ditto for `getent passwd` vs /etc/passwd, and `getent services` vs /etc/services, and more.  See `man getent`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
sed 's/:.*//' /etc/group
```